# Does window.opener work when on different domains?

Tags: javascript, iis

Will `window.opener` work if the child window is on a different domain than the parent window?

What about when it's the same domain on IIS7, but on a different application/virtual directory?

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't work from a child window in another domain than the parent window.
The error returned is permission denied. 
This is a security issue, which is by design.

If the child window and parent window are in the same domain (even if they are running on different virtual directory's or applications) it works fine.